# How can I test get request with curl on django?

Tags: python, django, curl, get

I am trying to test if a get request works but I am not sure how to do it in django.I have postgre database connected to django server and I am trying to test if I can get a GET request to work but I can't find nothing specific on the internet.

I have some experience with Flask testing apis but not with Django.

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
#from cameras.models import CameraQuerySet, Camera, CameraAuthenticationToken, CameraGroupQuerySet, CameraGroup, CameraStatusUpdate, CameraGroupLog
from . import models #if not up


@login_required
def camera_lookup(request):
    serial_number = request.GET.get('serial_number')
    found = 0
    if serial_number != None:
        serial_number = serial_number.lower()
        found = Camera.objects.filter(serial_number=serial_number).count()
    return HttpResponse(str(found), content_type="text/html", status=200)
```

urls.py

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path

app_name = 'cameras'

urlpatterns = [
    path('add/', views.add, name='add'),
    path(r'api/1.0/camera/', views.camera_lookup, name='camera_lookup'),
```

models.py

```
class Camera(TimeStampedModel):
    public_identifier = models.UUIDField(unique=True,
                                         default=uuid.uuid4,
                                         editable=False)

    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=100,
                                     unique=True,
                                     null=True)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

    group = models.ForeignKey('CameraGroup',
                              on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                              null=True,
                              related_name='cameras',
                              related_query_name='cameras')

    group_tracker = FieldTracker(fields=('group',))

    objects = CameraQuerySet.as_manager()

    #identifier from assembly (what parts does the camera consist of)
    bom                = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

    #what firmware is the camera on (mender artifact name)
    firmware           = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

    #last seen at ip
    last_sighting_ip   = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    last_sighting_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    #json blob that the camera can send home w. health status
    health = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Why do you want to test this with curl, rather than in the browser? What makes you think making a request is any different if the backend is Django rather than any other framework?

Comment: any tool that can communicate with your server over HTTP (a browser, curl, postman, ...) can be used to submit requests and should receive a response from your server. It's just HTTP. Nothing different from any other web framework.

Comment: sorry I am doing very bad at formulating what I mean. I am trying to test the camera_lookup request  but I am not sure if I wrote it correct in a first place. I tried curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/cameras/api/1.0/camera/?serial_number=1234 . But I is giving 302 code

Comment: 302 is redirect. Look at Location header to find out where this has been redirected to. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302)

Comment: I found the problem.I was importing the models like this "from . import models" and I had to change it to "from cameras.models import CameraQuerySet, Camera"

Comment: The funny thing is that I still get 302 for some reason with curl but when I put  the url with the key:value pair in the brawser it works fine

Comment: Can you add `-v` to curl to see the actual header responses (per this [old post](https://serverfault.com/questions/530116/curl-receiving-a-302-or-something-weird), possibly outdated) and find out the Location header

Answer (score 1):

I use Postman (which started out as a stack overflow post so I've no qualms recommending). Other tools are available.

**Advantages:**

1. You can GET, POST, PUT etc
2. Set the headers, authorisation tokens
3. use the console to see request and response headers
4. Just using it helped me understand api calls

**Disadvantages**

1. Not being a browser it won't alert you to CORS errors
2. request and response headers won't be identical to a browser issued request